# Google Sheets support with a query for unique values

Tags: google-sheets

I am working with the six columns of data attached[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbE9w.png). I am trying to write a formula that will do the following:

1. Return the data, from left to right, as C, B, A, D, E, F
2. Order the data by column C (Asc order)
3. Filter out duplicates in column B

The formula that I am using is `=QUERY(A:F,"SELECT C, Min(B), A, D, E, F WHERE A IS NOT NULL GROUP BY C, B, A, D, E, F ORDER BY C",1)`

This formula does not remove all duplicates as it appears to only be removing duplicates by all columns. If I only input 'GROUP BY B' only, the formula does not work.

Can anyone help me find a formula that will fit my requirements?

The sheet is >> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SVqY4gdV3A-lctbod9g4yY9eod8Jhvcr8rB-NH_RfuI/edit#gid=0

Thanks!

Comment: Can you ***manually*** enter the expected output for your sample dataset so as for us to get a clear picture and all?!

Comment: Sure thing. I have added this to the dataset.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SVqY4gdV3A-lctbod9g4yY9eod8Jhvcr8rB-NH_RfuI/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

*Here's an alternate `non-query` approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(Σ,sort(sortn(sort(A2:F12,3,1),9^9,2,1,1),3,1,2,1),
     choosecols(Σ,3,2,1,4,5,6))
```

[image]